# ¿Cuál es el Domain_id en los parámetros de la publicación de un producto?

Tags: mercadolibre

Al tratar de publicar un producto en Mercadolibre me arroja este json:

```
 {
        message: "Domain_id is required",
        error: 400,
        status: 400,
        cause: null
 }
```

Pero en ningún lugar encuentro qué es el Domain_id.

Es extraño ya que usando el Postman envío los datos del producto y se publica sin problemas pero al hacer la llamada desde mi app usando los mismos datos me da ese error.

Answer (score 0):

Todavía no sé que significa el "**Domain_id**", pero parece que tiene que ver con la **categoría** ya que estaba haciendo unas pruebas y la app me estaba dando error al seleccionar la categoría. Al solucionar el error pude enviar la misma data tal como lo hacía en Postman y **pude publicar el producto sin problemas**.

Si alguien tiene este error probablemente tenga que ver con la categoría.

Chequear nombres y valores de las variables para evitar este problema.